# Logistic Regression: how to compare predicted value with a threshold and get the classification done

Tags: python, logistic-regression, random-seed

I have this Credit Default dataset with head like this:

```
default student balance      income        default_Yes

No      No      729.526495   44361.625074   0 

No      Yes     817.180407   12106.134700   0 

No      No      1073.549164  31767.138947   0 

No      No      529.250605   35704.493935   0 

No      No      785.655883   38463.495879   0
```

I am trying to perform logistic regression for 'default_Yes' based on the 'balance' attribute and used the following function:

```
 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
 from sklearn import metrics
 X = cred_def[['balance']]
 Y = cred_def['default_Yes']
 X_train, X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3,random_state=76)
 logist = LogisticRegression()
 logist.fit(X_train,Y_train)
 y_pred = logist.predict(X_test)


 def model(threshold):
     def_thresh = np.greater(y_pred, threshold).astype(int)
     acc_score = metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, def_thresh)
     print(acc_score)
     plt.scatter(X_test.values,Y_test.values)
     plt.scatter(X_test.values,def_thresh)
     conf = metrics.confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)
     print(conf)
```

The problem I am facing is: no matter what value of `threshold` I am passing to the function 'model', it's producing same output and not considering the value passed.

Comment: random_state is supposed to be an integer (random seed), not boolean. There are 142 questions on  
 https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=random_state+parameter , we should make one canonical then close this in favor of it.

Comment: This is getting confusing, your title is grossly misleading: you **don't pass any parameters whatsoever to `logist = LogisticRegression()`**. You pass `random_state=True` to `train_test_split()`.  So LogisticRegression's defaults to random_state=None, which the doc tells you it uses some random number from the random-number generator. `train_test_split()` and `LogisticRegression()` do not somehow silently share parameters with each other. Seriously please read the doc on both and understand what the code is actually doing, then revise your question.

Comment: And `threshold` isn't a parameter to either splitting or LR training, it's a cutoff parameter in scoring the output of LR `predict()`. You could just train once and then watch/plot the effect  as you sweep `threshold` across a range of values.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (in response to the first two edits of this question statement): you don't pass any parameters whatsoever to `logist = LogisticRegression()`. You pass `random_state=True` to `train_test_split()`. Not to `LogisticRegression`.

`random_state` is supposed to be an integer (random seed), not boolean - read the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). So by passing `True`, which will get coerced to 1, you just keep setting `random_state = 1`.

Try it on some other integer values and you'll get different results.

EDIT2: Your issue had nothing to do with `random_state` parameter as originally titled. It is to do with your predicted values `y_pred = logist.predict(X_test)`, and specifically how behave as you sweep your `threshold` parameter across the possible range [0,1] of LR output values. Show us a table with at least five different values of threshold. Like [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0], and whatever value you mean by "the result". Next, what do you mean by "the result"? Your accuracy acc_score, your confusion matrix conf, or what? For now, forget confusion matrix. Just look at say the effect of applying different values of threshold to the same array of predicted values `y_pred`. Also, you want to sanity-check `y_pred`, inspect it. Is it all-one? all-zero? What are its mean, median etc. Please post a table of data. Do not just keep saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: Even if I provide random_state some value,same problem is coming.It should consider the value of argument 'threshold' provided during function call, but it keeps on producing same results for every value of threshold

Comment: Tell us what values of `threshold` you tried, already! You didn't put that in the question. Also, don't just tell us "it doesn't work", inspect `coef_`, the LR coefficients, and verify that they change and have meaningful values.

Comment: model(0.2) , model (0.6) and others as well and it keeps on producing same output.0.975333333333
[[2906    2]
 [  72   20]]

Comment: ...or plot a graph of the distribution of outputs

Comment: I am still not getting the solution ...I have made separate function for comparing predicted value with the threshold.If it's still not correct, can you please help me how to do the required comparison done.

Comment: I asked you to **watch/plot the effect as you sweep `threshold` across a range of values. Show us a table with at least five different values of threshold. Like `[0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0]`, and whatever value you mean by "the result"**. Next, what do you mean by "the result"? Your accuracy `acc_score`, your confusion matrix `conf`, or what? For now, forget confusion matrix. Just look at say the effect of applying different values of `threshold` to the same array of predicted values `y_pred`. Also, you want to sanity-check `y_pred`, inspect it. Is it all-one? all-zero? What is its mean, median etc

Comment: okay....got it now.The dataset is like this .For the values [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0],only at the value of 1.0, I got different value for accuracy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good news, just please still post those actual data. Show us (say) the first ten values of `y_pred`. Make sure those are acting sane before you try to measure accuracy, or anything higher up. Always check your assumptions.